# Why same document is repeating in diferent webparts - sharepoint foundation 2013

Tags: web-part, document

I'm basically trying to create different pages with document webpart but to have different documents uploaded inside. Right now if i upload one document in one webpart, same document will be displayed in all pages where i have document webpart. What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've basically find the issue. I had just to create new library app with different name and then to use it on other page. Very silly stuff but manage to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not really familiar with web parts, but I'm sure the web parts are saving their documents to a library. They are probably saving (and retrieving) to the same library, this should be configurable in the web part settings.